# Running tokens Discord.py

Tags: python, discord

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

tokens = [
    'dgfggg.YJK14Q.rgrgrgrgrgrgrgrgrg-ZjlvsPyQXE',
    'adddawd.YJK3BQ.grsggrgrgrgrgrg-Y',
    'wadwdwad.YJK37g.gfregrgegfegefte4tyg'
]

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="//")


for token in tokens:
    print(token)
    bot.run(f"{token}", bot=False)
```

Why won't this work is there any way to run tokens like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can run multiple bot with `asyncio` module by creating multiple tasks that will run on the same thread at the same time. This is an old script written by me from a while ago:

```
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

tokens = ['token1', 'token2', 'token3']

class myBot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    async def on_ready(self):
        print('bot ready')

try:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tasks = []
    for i, token in enumerate(tokens): # putting all of the bot tokens into tasks
        temp = myBot(command_prefix='//')
        temp.token = token
        try:
            # Using .start function here because .run, .connect, and .login functions all have some complex checks for "connection" I'm not 100% sure what the difference between those functions are, but hey, .start function works fine.
            tasks.append(loop.create_task( temp.start(token) ))
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'unable to login into bot #{str(i)}')
    # run the bots
    gathered = asyncio.gather(*tasks, loop=loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(gathered)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Exiting...')
```

Note: you have to make sure all of the tokens in the `tokens` list to be valid or you can create a token checker. Otherwise, the script will throw you an invalid token error.